# Is it possible to install Oracle Database Express on 32bit Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, oracle

If it is possible, how is the step-by-step installation done?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-functioning-of-oracle-xe-in-the-system-oraclehome-environment-variable

**Install Oracle 10g XE on Ubuntu Server**

**Download**

oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb (262,440,214 bytes) (cksum 3404538446) *Debian package

**from**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/102xelinsoft-102048.html

After downloading install the deb package with the gdebi installer or with

```
sudo dpkg -i oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb
```

After-install configuration

You must configure Oracle TCP/IP port and other parameters. Simply type the following command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Output:

### Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Configuration

This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 10g Express
Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should
be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that
will be used for database accounts.  Press  to accept the defaults.
Ctrl-C will abort.

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]: [Enter key] or 
 [write your port if 8080 is in use]

Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:[Enter key]

Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of
different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after
initial configuration:secret

Confirm the password:secret

Do you want Oracle Database 10g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done

Configuring Database...Done

Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance...Done

Installation Completed Successfully.

To access the Database Home Page go to "http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex"

To access the Database Home Page go to "http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex". Open a web browser and type url (you need to use username "system" and password setup earlier)

Comment: When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex
I get this:
Unable to connect  
          Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
First install `libaio1` package with:

```
 sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

After that install the downloaded deb file with:

```
 sudo dpkg -i oracle-xe_xxxxx_i386.deb
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems my .deb isn't detected

sudo: unable to resolve host c031-mak1
dpkg: error processing home/Downloads/oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory

Comment: Is the file really there? Are you in that directory? If you cannot manage it, install `gdebi` and double click on the deb file! (GUI mode install)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Oracle Database 11g Express Edition a.k.a Oracle XE doesn't support Linux 32-bit architecture